# Как загрузить файл в arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Мне нужно загрузить файл в arraylist и заменить определенные строки, после записать мой лист в другой файл, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как один из возможных вариантов, логика изменения строк остается за тобой, в примере к каждой строке добавлено слово "Changes"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader buf = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("text.txt"))
         ; BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("NewText.txt"))) {

        //Добавили все строки из файла в List
        list = buf.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());

        //Изменили строки как нам нужно
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String currentString = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, currentString + " Changes");
        }

        //Записали в новый файл
        for (String st : list) {
            writer.write(st + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```